# Changing levels in R

Tags: r, levels

I have a field where the levels are broken down as below:

```
levels(demo$age)
"18 to 24 years old"    "25 to 34 years old"    "35 to 44 years old"    "45 to 54 years old"    "55 to 64 years old"    "65 to 74 years old"    "75 years old or older"
```

How can I change the levels to

```
 "Total " "18 to 24 years old" "25 plus".
```

Comment: You can do `v1 <- c("25 to 34 years old", "35 to 44 years old", ...); levels(demo$age)[levels(demo$age) %in% v1] <- "25 plus"`

Comment: It is not clear about the 'Total' level.  Are you doing any aggregation and then need this level.  It is better to show a small reproducible example

Comment: I want to create a new level total which would the sum of all levels of age.

Comment: But your age is a factor column?

Comment: Yes ,age is a factor column

Comment: Anyway, the question is to create some levels for the 'age' and I think the solution below should work\

Answer (score 0):

We create a `vector` of `levels` that needs to be changed

```
v1 <- c("25 to 34 years old", "35 to 44 years old", "45 to 54 years old", 
  "55 to 64 years old",   "65 to 74 years old" ,  "75 years old or older")
```

then, assign those to new level

```
levels(demo$age)[levels(demo$age) %in% v1] <- "25 plus"
```

If we need a 'Total' level as well

```
levels(demo$age) <- c("Total", levels(demo$age))
levels(demo$age)
#[1] "Total"              "18 to 24 years old" "25 plus"
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
demo <- data.frame(age = sample(c("18 to 24 years old", v1), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: I get the total as a new level but it doesnt seem to be aggregating the values of other levels.

Comment: @SNT Then, please show a small reproducible example with expected output